# How can I set initial React state from API data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a rest API back end set up. I want to set values inside the `getInitialState` function for a component, but I can't figure out how to populate the object I need to return because I am using an asynchronous http request. The object I return has undefined values, as expected. How do I get around this?

I'm using fetch (can switch to any other library, honestly) as of now. I can't figure out how to call `getInitialState` after the asynchronous call has returned some value instead of before it happens.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {

  render() {

    // I basically need to call getInitialState after the last promise has been resolved
    fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/aye')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      // Need to return some values from this.
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.jsonReturnedValue}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should call `this.setState` in order to change `state` values

```js
export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      jsonReturnedValue: null
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/aye')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: json });
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{ this.state.jsonReturnedValue }</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I was basically checking for authentication. When I first set the isLogged state to false, and then set it to true after the call, there's this flash of the not logged in page before the logged in page is displayed. Wanted to know how to get rid of that.

Comment: @Zeokav maybe you need add new state, for instance `loading` - http://jsbin.com/hasitexira/edit?js,output

Comment: Just added a loading component and another state. Works perfectly. Thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 5):

In your situation -

It's better to get the rendering done for the first time with empty state data lets say

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data : []
    };
}
```

and make ajax call in `componentDidMount`, this is the place where you can perform dom manipulation and send `ajax` request to fetch data via `REST`.

After new data is fetched from server set the state with new data

```
this.setState({data:newDataFromServer});
```

e.g In `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
 sendAjaxRequest()
 .then(
      (newDataFromServer) => {
              this.setState({data : newDataFromServer });

     });
}
```

This will cause the **re-rendering** to happen with latest data fetched from server and new state changes will be reflected.

Answer (score 4):

You should do something along the following. Firstly, create the `state` in the `constructor` method. This will then allow you to use this value in your `render` method by referencing `{this.state.jsonReturnedValue}`. The `constructor()` method is the ES6 version of `getInitialState()` in case you are not aware of this. This is where you should set the `state` of the component.

Then in the `componentDidMount` which will run after the `render` method you can make the API call api and use React's `setState` method to update the value of `this.state.jsonReturnedValue`.

When `this.setState()` runs and sets a new value it will then run the `render` method again and update the view accordingly.

```
export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
        jsonReturnedValue: null
     }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.jsonList();
  }

  jsonList() {
     fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/aye')
    .then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        jsonReturnedValue: response.json()
      }) 
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.jsonReturnedValue}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```